# How can I tell which process I am debugging (attached to multiple processes) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, attach-to-process

I'm debugging a Windows service which has two running instances, by attaching to both instances.  I am doing this because I know only one instance will hit my breakpoint, but I'd like to know which instance that is, so that I don't have to attach to both in future.

Is there a way, when attached to multiple processes, that you can tell which one has hit a breakpoint?  A trial-and-error solution would be to attach one at a time and see if the breakpoint is hit, or, stop one of the services (through [Services.msc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/error-1783-services-msc)) and see which process ID disappears, but neither solution seems scale-able to me.  Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add a watch to the following statement:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id
```

This gives you the PID (process id) you are attached to.
You can look for pids in windows task manager (Menu View->Select Columns and tick PID).

Hope this helps

Comment: Both solutions work, though this one is more succinct in retrieving the ID through the watch window so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Can also use ProcessName instead of ID to give something a bit more relevent (assuming the process name is clear)

Answer (score 10):

That's what the Processes window is for (Debug->Windows->Processes, or Ctrl+Alt+Z).

Comment: The ID column in that window is the PID. If it's hex and you want it in decimal (ala Task Manager), switch to the Autos window, right-click and flip the Hexadecimal Display option, then switch back to the Processes window.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the "When Hit..." option available on a breakpoint (right click on the breakpoint, it's in the context menu that pops up). You can then print a message with the value of a variable along with lots of other information, such as:

$ADDRESS - Current Instruction

$CALLER - Previous Function Name

$CALLSTACK - Call Stack

$FUNCTION - Current Function Name

**$PID - Process ID**

**$PNAME - Process Name**

$TID - Thread ID

$TNAME - Thread Name

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables