# More Visual Differentiation between multiple startup debug processes in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Is there a more visual way to differentiate what process you are busy debugging when hitting a break point and then switching between the processes using the process drop down?

Something in the line of different background windows colors per process?

Possibly a add on or plugin?

Comment: What about this issue? Would you please share the latest information about this issue in your side?

Comment: @ Fletch Zhou-MSFT  Nothing new . I also didn't find any plugins so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, I haven’t found any plug-in that could highlight the process that is currently debugging in Visual Studio. 
But the tools those Visual Studio offers could help us to differentiate them while multi-process debugging:

[image]

You can see there are two places where we could find out the current process under debugging:
In the process window (**Debug -> Windows -> Processes**), it gives the golden arrow.

In the right hand, at the top of Diagnostic Tools, there is also a pop-up which indicates the process with PID that is under debugging. 
I also found thread talking about the similar issue which also might help:

[How can I tell which process I am debugging (attached to multiple processes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442797/how-can-i-tell-which-process-i-am-debugging-attached-to-multiple-processes)

Comment: Jup found all of these also and while these work they aren't very visual

Comment: @Alien_SM Maybe there are some other third-part tools which could help to display it more visually, but at present the default ones in Visual Studio just work like above.I will update it if I can find a better tool for this, of course you also could share it with us if you find any.